# Reinserting set element creates holes

Tags: python, set

Generally if we need to insert an object to a set, we should make it hash-able (by implementing the hash function) and comparable (and implementing a compare function). Set does not provide a mechanism to access its elements and thus cannot be mutated directly though can easily be circumvented.
A general pattern to mutate a set item would be as follows

```
i = next(iter(x))
update(i)
x.add(i)
```

This generally seem to work for almost all cases except one when unexpected holes are created.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.count = 0
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, ))
    def __iadd__(self, n):
        self.count += n
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x


>>> x = {Foo(1)}
>>> i = next(iter(x))
>>> i+=1
>>> x.add(i)
>>> x
set([None, <__main__.Foo object at 0x0279D8B0>])
```

My guess is mutating a set element while updating may cause unexpected behavior but invoking next would just fetch the value (a copy I guess) that should not be an issue.

Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: What is an "unexpected hole"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__),

> [`__iadd__`] should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) **and
>     return the result** (which could be, but does not have to be, self)

Therefore,

```
def __iadd__(self, n):
    self.count += n
    return self
```

Then,

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.count = 0
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, ))
    def __iadd__(self, n):
        self.count += n
        return self
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x

x = {Foo(1)}
i = next(iter(x))
i+=1
x.add(i)
print(x)
```

yields

```
set([<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f19ae8b9f10>])
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to return self in **iadd** method.